# VBA Paste on filtered sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, autofilter

I want to paste copied cells into only visible cells inside a sheet where the filter is active using VBA

Thinking it would be a simple task I initially create a sub like this:

```
Public Sub PasteFlt()
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

but it doesn't work at all

After a lot of tries and debugging I finally made it work using this code:

```
Public Sub PasteFlt()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim rDest As Range, rSrc As Range
    Dim tCell As Range
    Dim r As Integer, tR As Integer
    Dim c As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rDest = Selection
    Worksheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Set rSrc = Selection

    r = 0
    tR = 0
    For Each tCell In rDest.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If (tCell.row - rDest.row + 1) > tR Then
            r = r + 1
            tR = tCell.row - rDest.row + 1
        End If
        c = tCell.Column - rDest.Column + 1
        If r <= rSrc.Rows.Count Then
            If c <= rSrc.Columns.Count Then
                tCell.Value = rSrc(r, c)
            End If
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next tCell

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub
```

It does what I want but I don't really like it.
My question is: Is there an easier way on doing so without creating and deleting a new sheet, like my first attempt? Maybe I'm simply missing something there

Comment: Are you trying to convert filtered rows to values (eliminating formulas)? Explain in more detail.

Comment: I want to paste cells that i copy from other sheets or workbooks into a sheet containing filtered rows ignoring the hidden ones

Comment: The code that I posted does the trick, but it's slow and It creates and then deletes a temporary sheet only for storing data. I ask If it's possible to do it in an easier (And faster) way

Comment: It looks like you're copying the filtered rows to a new sheet and then pasting the rows from the new sheet back as values to the filtered rows. Are you?

Comment: No, the rows that I copied aren't filtered. I do the copy before running the macro. I didn't post the code because I i do it directly form excel. My idea is to assign this macro to a shortcut. I pasted in a different sheet only because I didn't find a better way to extract the copied cells values

Comment: Is the range in the clipboard a single-area range? Can it have more or fewer rows and/or columns than the destination (filtered) range? Do you know the names of the worksheets, the one from which you have copied a range to the clipboard and of course, the one that is filtered? I don't see a better way unless I can reference each range i.e. the Selection would become the selected range on the first (source, 'clipboard') worksheet (no need to copy) which would then be copied into the filtered range on the second (destination, filtered) worksheet. Also, choose the final active worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

This is a procedure I wrote in reply to a question posted elsewhere - it may or may not suit your requirement:-

```
Sub filteredCopyPaste()
    Dim source As Range, destination As Range
    Dim addresses() As String, otherBook As String
    Dim cell As Range, i As Long, width As Integer
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Do
        Set source = Application.InputBox("Select the range* to be copied" + vbNewLine _
                                                                + "* include the header(s)", "Source data...", , , , , , 8)
    Loop While source Is Nothing
    
    width = source.Columns.Count
    
tryAgain:
    Do
        Set destination = Application.InputBox("Select the range* to be pasted" + vbNewLine _
                                                                    + "* include the header(s)", "Destination data...", , , , , , 8)
    Loop While destination Is Nothing
    
    If destination.Columns.Count <> width Then
        MsgBox "The area to be pasted must be of the same width" + vbNewLine + _
                        "   as the area from which data are being copied", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Wrong size!"
        GoTo tryAgain
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set source = source.Offset(1, 0).Resize(source.Rows.Count - 1, width).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set destination = destination.Offset(1, 0).Resize(destination.Rows.Count - 1, width).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    If source.Cells.Count <> destination.Cells.Count Then
        MsgBox "The number of filtered cells in the source range differs from" + vbNewLine + _
                        "       the number of filtered cells in the destination range.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Unequal ranges selected!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    ReDim addresses(1 To source.Rows.Count)
 
    If source.Parent.Parent.Name <> destination.Parent.Parent.Name Then
        otherBook = "'[" & source.Parent.Parent.Name & "]"
    Else
        otherBook = "'"
    End If
    
    i = 1
    For Each cell In source.Rows
        addresses(i) = otherBook & cell.Parent.Name & "'!" & cell.Address
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
    
    i = 1
    For Each cell In destination.Rows
        Range(addresses(i)).Copy cell
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Spectral Instance, thank you for your reply.
It doesn't completely suit my requirement but for sure it's a great food for thought. Asking for the source range using an InputBox solves the problem of having to create and then delete a temporary new sheet

Answer (score 0):

This procedure proposed by **@Spectral Instance** can be shortened a bit, but it is important whether both the source and destination ranges are non-continuous or only the target. I give two proposals suitable for each of these cases.

```
Sub filteredCopyPaste2()
    ' single loop, source range is continuous
    Dim source As Range, destination As Range
    Dim cell As Range, i As Long, width As Integer
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set source = Application.InputBox("Select the range* to be copied" + vbNewLine _
               & "* include the header(s)", "Source data...", , , , , , 8)
    If source Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    width = source.Columns.Count
    
tryAgain:
    Set destination = Application.InputBox("Select the range* to be pasted" & vbNewLine _
             & "* include the header(s)", "Destination data...", , , , , , 8)
    If destination Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    If destination.Columns.Count <> width Then
        MsgBox "The area to be pasted must be of the same width" & vbNewLine & _
               "   as the area from which data are being copied", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Wrong size!"
        GoTo tryAgain
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set source = source.Offset(1, 0).Resize(source.Rows.Count - 1, width) '  continuous range
    Set destination = destination.Offset(1, 0).Resize(destination.Rows.Count - 1, width).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    If source.Cells.Count <> destination.Cells.Count Then
        MsgBox "The number of filtered cells in the source range differs from" & vbNewLine & _
               "       the number of filtered cells in the destination range.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Unequal ranges selected!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
 
    i = 1
    ' it is strange, however it works
    For Each cell In destination.Rows
        cell.Value = source.Rows(i).Value
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
End Sub

Sub filteredCopyPaste3()   ' two loops, both ranges filtered
    Dim source As Range, destination As Range
    Dim addresses() As String
    Dim cell As Range, i As Long, width As Integer
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set source = Application.InputBox("Select the range* to be copied" + vbNewLine _
                                & "* include the header(s)", "Source data...", , , , , , 8)
    If source Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    width = source.Columns.Count
    
tryAgain:
    Set destination = Application.InputBox("Select the range* to be pasted" & vbNewLine _
              & "* include the header(s)", "Destination data...", , , , , , 8)
    If destination Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    If destination.Columns.Count <> width Then
        MsgBox "The area to be pasted must be of the same width" & vbNewLine & _
               "   as the area from which data are being copied", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Wrong size!"
        GoTo tryAgain
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set source = source.Offset(1, 0).Resize(source.Rows.Count - 1, width).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set destination = destination.Offset(1, 0).Resize(destination.Rows.Count - 1, width).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    If source.Cells.Count <> destination.Cells.Count Then
        MsgBox "The number of filtered cells in the source range differs from" & vbNewLine & _
               "       the number of filtered cells in the destination range.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Unequal ranges selected!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    ReDim addresses(1 To source.Count / width)   ' total rows count
 
    i = 1
    ' it is strange, however it works
    For Each cell In source.Rows
        addresses(i) = cell.Address(External:=True)
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
    
    i = 1
    For Each cell In destination.Rows
        Range(addresses(i)).Copy cell
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not thrilled that the source and destination have to be the same size, but if i want to optimize it I suppose there aren't many alternatives